# What is a "confidence maneuver"?

Tags: air-traffic-control, terminology

[Order JO 7110.65T Section 6 Part 5-6-1](http://tfmlearning.faa.gov/Publications/atpubs/ATC/atc0506.html) says

> Vector aircraft:
>   a. In controlled airspace for separation, safety, noise abatement, operational advantage, **confidence maneuver**, or when a pilot requests. Allow aircraft operating on an RNAV route to remain on their own navigation to the extent possible.

**What is a confidence maneuver?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As quoted from the entry in the [Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg.pdf):

> CONFIDENCE MANEUVER− A confidence maneuver
>   consists of one or more turns, a climb or
>   descent, or other maneuver to determine if the pilot
>   in command (PIC) is able to receive and comply with
>   ATC instructions.

This could be useful if the controller suspects a hijacking, hypoxia, radio failure, or other situations that would compromise reception and execution of ATC instructions.

Perhaps the best example of an implementation of this would be when ATC suspects a partial aircraft radio failure; a confidence maneuver vector might enable ATC to determine that the pilot was still able to receive instructions, though aircraft radio transmission might be compromised.

Comment: In the case of attempting to troubleshoot a communications issue *only*, a simple "N12345, if you hear this transmission, ident" is easier and quicker. Otherwise I agree completely.

Comment: @randomhead Yes, assuming that the aircraft is so equipped. That technology is new, relative to the introduction of the Confidence Maneuver. Most aircraft now flying in the US do have transponders, but many do not, especially those without electrical systems. By it's very nature the Confidence Maneuver is rare.

Comment: That's not correct. [JO 7110.65T CHG 2](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7110.65TCHG2.pdf) (3/10/2011): *This changes adds “Confidence Maneuver” as a reason for issuing a vector. This change cancels and incorporates [N JO 7110.534, Confidence Maneuver and No Radio (NORDO)](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/N7110.534.pdf), effective October 1, 2010.*

Comment: You may be right about this particular application of the term confidence maneuver to ATC vectoring. The concept of a confidence maneuver from a pilot perspective has been around for decades, at least dating back to the early 70s.